# Convert to date format ignoring a character

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame with dates as column names. The dates have an "x" before the actual date. Is there a possibility to convert the column names to data format despite the "x" before it?
I tried the following, which didn't lead me to wished result:

```
Date<-c("X2013.02","X2013.03","X2013.04","X2013.05")
as.Date(Date,"%Y,%m")
[1] NA NA NA NA
as.Date(Date,"%XY,%m")
[1] NA NA NA NA
as.Date(Date,"X%Y,%m")
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also `as.yearmon` from the "zoo" package:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(Date, format="X%Y.%m")
# [1] "Feb 2013" "Mar 2013" "Apr 2013" "May 2013"

as.Date(as.yearmon(Date, format="X%Y.%m"))
# [1] "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-05-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Date<-c("X2013.02","X2013.03","X2013.04","X2013.05")
as.Date(paste0(Date, ".01"),"X%Y.%m.%d")
#[1] "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-05-01"
```

Note that `Date`s need a day. Also, you may want to consider setting `check.names = FALSE` when you import your data with `read.table` or one of its relatives.

Comment: The reason is that a date is not complete without a year month and day portion.   So R doesn't know what to do with only a year and month.

Comment: Your version delivers what I need, but the other one is, despite the necessity to load a package, more intuitive. Furthermore, I often need a combination of year and month, which I achieved until now using the annoying `paste`.